# Spectral Theorem for Unitary Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

It is well known that the following - in many literature - called the Spectral Theorem for Unitary Operator.

I would like to know where i can find further information about it and its proof.

[image]

Comment: I like the first Chapter of Folland's Abstract Harmonic Analysis. There is also a short book of Arveson devoted to spectral theory 'A Short Course on Spectral Theory'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about being unitary here. The key property is that unitaries operators are **normal**. So you should search for the Spectral Theorem for normal operators.

One source I know is Section IX.2 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.